# .so file is missing while running C++ app

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, makefile, ldd

I am trying to deploy my app as a docker container. I was able to build the app inside the container. I started the container and run `ldd myapp` command inside it to obtain the list of all dependencies. Then I added new stage to my dockerfile which copied all these dependencies from earlier build stage along with myapp itself. All dependencies had absolute path, except one:

```
libDependency.so => /ws/MyApp/Module/../../Dependency/lib/libDependency.so (0x00007f8dff102000)
```

Corresponding to this, I had following line added to my dockerfile:

```
COPY --from=builder /ws/MyApp/Module/../../Dependency/lib/libDependency.so /ws/MyApp/Module/../../Dependency/lib/libDependency.so
```

I was able to build the image. However when I try to run the app from inside the container, it gives me following error:

```
$ docker run -it app:0.1 /usr/bin/bash
bash-5.0# /ws/MyApp/build/MyApp
/ws/MyApp/build/MyApp: error while loading shared libraries: libDependency.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However I checked that this file is indeed there at the path

```
 /ws/Dependency/lib/libDependency.so
```

This `.so` file is referenced in `CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
SET(DEPENDENCY_LIB ${DEPENDENCY_LIB_DIR}/lib/libDependency.so)
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Does the directory `/ws/MyApp/Modele` exist in your docker container?  If not then the path `/ws/MyApp/Modele/../../Dependency/lib` cannot be resolved.

Comment: Indeed ... I just copied dependencies ... for absolute dependencies it created those paths, but for relative dependencies it obviously did not create that folder since the dependency was located in ancestor directory !!! That directory was used only for relative reference ...

Comment: No no... you can change the `/ws/MyApp/Modele/../../Dependency/lib` into `/ws/Dependency/lib`, but the kernel, to search for the file needs to pass to `MyApp` and `Modele` to then go up both directories in sequence.  The path is not canonical and has this problem.  The linux kernel will not be able to deduct that those two directories don't exist.  If it cannot traverse the full path will tell you `ENOTDIR` and the native code will fail.  That dependency is not relatie, as it starts with `/`.